# How to set the DataGridView to not accept empty value?

Tags: c#

I am using windows forms c# . Anyone knows how to set the `DataGridView` to not to accept empty value. because I do not want the user to insert empty values . Thank you

Comment: Could you please explain what you have tried so far to achieve this goal? Also, please include details and code containing the DataGridView initialization in the question. These will help us in giving more accurate answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can check value of cells on null or empty in your code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dataRow in this.yourDataGridView.Rows)
{
  for (int index = 0; index < dataRow.Cells.Count; index++)
  {
    if (dataRow.Cells[index].Value == null || dataRow.Cells[index].Value == System.DBNull.Value || string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataRow.Cells[index].Value.ToString()))
    {
        // here is your logic...
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add CellValueChanged event to your dataGridView control

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == null)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
```